# Problem registering Push Notifications. HELP!

Tags: iphone, notifications, push, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I've recently started developing iphone applications for a project at school and I've been having some problems testing push notifications. I've read I need to get some SSL certificate from the program portal, but I cannot find the link AppID where I am supposed to get them. Is it really necesary even though I am just starting out making some tests in XCode? What else do I need to run push notifications?
I've started coding the client side, but I cannot register for remote notifications. (I run registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:..., but it cannot register) I think it is because I don´t have the certificates, but I really don´t know.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you need to be enrolled in developer programe.you can not test push notification for free.